# Where is this proxy entry being read from in Eclipse?

Tags: proxy, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

When I install Eclipse I see the following and navigate to Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections I see the following proxy entry :

[image]

Where is this proxy entry being read from? I have installed Eclipse on separate machines and this entry is not configured in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your system proxy config. On windows, you can find this in IE's LAN configuration.